# How can I open a .nsi file?

Tags: file, cmd

I have downloaded a .nsi file and now I have to launch this to get my missing Windows registry keys installed. I tried different things to open it but so far everything didnt work. Can anyone please tell me how to run this kind of files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A .nsi file is an input to the process that creates an executable.  You need the Nullsoft Scriptable Install System compiler: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Download

More info: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Simple_tutorials